# When using QGIS Modeler with geopackages is there any way to Extract one Specific layer when using clip function?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage

I would like to use QGIS modeler to allow extraction of certain layers of a geopackage.

I am trying to clip a geopackage containing multiple layers using modeler and when run it the output gives only one layer within the clip boundary which is the first layer in the list, as it begins with A. (abandoned sewer)

What I would like to know is there something I have to add after .gpkg such as

layer.gpkg|layername='layername'

that QGIS will understand as I cant get the syntax right to complete this operation.

I am using the 3.4.5 LTR version of QGIS

Comment: I thought I had a solution with *Load layer into project* but it seems, the few times I used the algorithm, I was loading an arbitrary layer that was the correct one only by chance.